# How can I use distinct() with an F() expression?

Tags: django

My count contains duplicates in this query:

```
items = items.annotate(
            user_id=F("product__items__user_id"),
            start_month=TruncMonth("start")
        ) \
            .values("user_id", "start_month") \
            .annotate(count=Count("start_month"))
```

I would need to apply `distinct()` to the F expression somehow to avoid getting duplicates, is this possible?

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Count` has a distinct parameter that needs to be set in this case:

```
items = items.annotate(
            user_id=F("product__items__user_id"),
            start_month=TruncMonth("start")
        ) \
            .values("user_id", "start_month") \
            .annotate(count=Count("start_month", distinct=True))
```

So I didn't need distinct() with an F() expression (which I don't think is possible, in another case I would have tried to use a Subquery)